# how to set user foreign key as current user django ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

my ajax django are working perfectly and my comments is also reaching, but when i put foreignkey user it says undefined

**ajax**

$(document).ready(function(){

```
        setInterval(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:"{% url 'comments' %}",
                success:function(response){
                   $('.display').empty();
                   for(var key in response.comments){
                       
                       console.log(response.comments[key].user)
                       var temp = "<p>"+response.comments[key].message+"</p>"
                       $(".display").append(temp);
                   }
                },
                error:function(response){
                    console.log("no data found")
                    alert("no data found")
                }

            }); 
        }, 500);

    });

</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
return render(request,'display/index.html')

def getusers(request):
    queryset =models.comments.objects.all()[:20]
    return JsonResponse({"comments":list(queryset.values())})
```

**models**

```
class comments(models.Model):
     userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     message = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
     date = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.user} comments'
```

in my admin when i select users and save , in template it is saying undefined, pls help mee

Comment: you could use `console.log` to see what data is returned in `success` of ajax, then itreate over that data

Comment: If the foreign key field is `user` then `.values()` will return the dictionary key as `user_id` (this will only be the primary key of the related model and not an instance)

Comment: pls edit the code